# How to fix Auth0 provider configuration to resolve 'Grant: missing session or misconfigured provider' error in Strapi?

Tags: authentication, auth0, strapi

I cannot receive a JWT token and user from response, when Im trying to send

```
${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/api/connect/auth0/callback? +
tokenQuery.
```

Instead, Ive got

```
Response.url = http://localhost:1337/?error=Grant%3A%20missing%20session%20or%20misconfigured%20provider
```

I have used this article: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/users-permissions#authentication

Auth0 provider settings:

server.ts:

I configured the provider according to the documentation, but unfortunately it doesn't work.